# Validate textarea onkeyup not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, onkeyup

I am trying to validate textarea onkeyup (in real time). The goal is to allow only words starting with this character: "ch or Ch". I put together some code, but it does not work and I dont know what is wrong...

```
<form method="post">
    <textarea name="test" pattern="ch+" id="test" onkeyup="validateTextarea"></textarea>
</form>

function validateTextarea() {
        var errorMsg = "Please match the format requested.";
        var textarea = this;
        var pattern = new RegExp('^' + $(textarea).attr('pattern') + '$');
        // check each line of text
        $.each($(this).val().split("\n"), function () {
            // check if the line matches the pattern
            var hasError = !this.match(pattern);
            if (typeof textarea.setCustomValidity === 'function') {
                textarea.setCustomValidity(hasError ? errorMsg : '');
            } else {
                $(textarea).toggleClass('error', !!hasError);
                $(textarea).toggleClass('ok', !hasError);
                if (hasError) {
                    $(textarea).attr('title', errorMsg);
                } else {
                    $(textarea).removeAttr('title');
                }
            }
            return !hasError;
        });
    }
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jbtRU/93/

The thing I want to do, is to disable all words in the textarea and allow only words starting with "Ch" or "ch"...

Comment: Please change ` onkeyup="validateTextarea"` to ` onkeyup="validateTextarea()"`, then do some basic troubleshooting.

Comment: And do you know what your req expression is actually testing for? https://regexper.com/#%5Ech%2B%24

Comment: I am sorry, but I really dont know what I am doing... I glued the code like a nest and now I am stucked. I really dont know how to code to be honest. I am learnig by trying things, and if they work, I try to figure it how and why, and if they are not, I am just stuck. And now I am just stucked. Thank You both for trying to help me, but I dont know how to fix it...

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind the keyup event as below
see working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jbtRU/106/

```
$(function() {
    $('#test').on('keyup', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
     var errorMsg = "Please match the format requested.";
        var textarea = $(this);
        var pattern = new RegExp('^' + $(textarea).attr('pattern') + '$');
        $.each(textarea.val().split("\n"), function (key, value) {
            // check if the line matches the pattern
            var hasError = !value.match(pattern);
            if (typeof textarea.setCustomValidity === 'function') {
                textarea.setCustomValidity(hasError ? errorMsg : '');
            } else {
                $(textarea).toggleClass('error', !!hasError);
                $(textarea).toggleClass('ok', !hasError);
                if (hasError) {
                    $(textarea).attr('title', errorMsg);
                } else {
                    $(textarea).removeAttr('title');
                }
            }
            return !hasError;
        });
  });
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to disable/delete/dont allow to type characters if the word doesnt start with "Ch" or "ch"?